# How to manage different API versions in a Perl module?

Tags: perl, api, module, datatables, cpan

There is a [DataTables CPAN module](https://metacpan.org/pod/DataTables). It is for datatables version 1.6. 
In the meantime, there is datatables 1.10, with a different interface. A lot of things changed, e.g. the option names.

I wonder: how could the module be extended to cover the old stuff as well as the new datatables 1.10 interface?
Is there a common name for this issue?
Is there a best practice for it? 
Is there a good reference module I could have a look at? I assume that others did face the challenge as well.

Comment: See also [JQuery::DataTables::Request](https://metacpan.org/pod/JQuery::DataTables::Request): "*This module only provides an API that corresponds to the v1.10 parameters but maps the v1.9 parameters to the corresponding v1.10 parameters.*"

Comment: Those two modules have quite the different interface. The DataTables assumes CGI and does all the parsing itself, while JQuery::DataTables::Request actually wants you to pass in args. I think the latter is the better, more abstract implementation. You should be able to work with that. In the meantime, it might make sense to make pull requests to both of them (https://github.com/srchulo/DataTables and https://github.com/xmikew/p5-JQuery-DataTables-Request) to add links to each other, so future users will see that there are implementations for both API versions.

Answer (score 0):

From my own author's point of view, best practice is to

1. keep latest master with latest API.
2. keep minor version of module with major version of API.
3. recommend module users to

   3.1. upgrade API together with module, or

   3.2. keep its module minor version untouched with version requirement (I did with cpanfile or cartonfile).

May You need more concrete answer?

Comment: It's nice to get some feedback about the topic. However, I'm interested in how to actually do it, to allow to use different API versions. Your proposal means to support only 1 api version per module.

Comment: One API version per module minor version is OK because you control both sides.

Module user allowed to install required API Server, and install/require API Client of latest patch version corresponding to the API.

Support for multiple API versions in one module is another task that should be done when module user doesn't own API server side.

Comment: I think I understand your answer, but it is not what I am looking for. I'm not the owner of the js DataTables library. Also, I consider the approach of having to install specific outdated (not the latest) versions of a module to get a standard behavoir quit uncommon. I personally would not consider this acptable for the average end user.